# about regex: is it useful in any situation to put whole pattern in parenthesis?

Tags: php, regex

Say you have a pattern like this:

```
@[a-z]+\s[\d]
```

is it useful to have something like this:

```
(@[a-z]+\s[\d])
```

in any situation? Is there any difference between them? How so?

Comment: Generally saying, round brackets are used for grouping and creating backreferences. But if these regexes stand alone then there is no real difference between them. The only difference is that the second one gets a backreference (\1). See http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html for more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `()` are used for capturing data. If you try to match `"My name is John"` without capturing:

```
/My name is [A-Z][a-z]+/
```

Then the result would simply be the string:

```
("My name is John")
```

If you want to capture the name separately from the result then you can use the `()` like this:

```
/My name is ([A-Z][a-z]+)/
```

This will return the entire match (it is a convention to always return the entire match as the first result item), and it will also return the captured name, like so:

```
("My name is John", "John")
```

If we want to capture the first and last name in `"My name is John Doe"` then we can do it like this:

```
/My name is ([A-Z][a-z]+) ([A-Z][a-z]+)/
```

The result:

```
("My name is John Doe", "John", "Doe")
```

So, to answer your question, there is really no difference between the two expressions. The first will just match a string, while the second will match and capture it (in this case you would basicaly just end up with two identical results).

Comment: @SverriMOlsen Thanks for the effort. I guess they are plain same then? Can we say all regex are in () by default? ( The whole expression )

Answer (score -3):

generally you put it in double quotes...

Comment: '[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}' OR "[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}" hope this helps

Comment: @IdsZay you can edit your answer to include the information from your comment, it will make it easier for people to find.